# Spring security custom Authenticator not called after spring/spring security version upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I upgrade spring and spring security to latest versions, in testing out basic functionality my Authenticator (which works with spring and spring security version 3) doesn't work with spring security 4. (I am moving to jdk 8 so due to asm conflicts I can't use old versions anymore). What config change do I need to make to support the new version of spring:

here is my web.xml:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID"
    version="3.0">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>excludePatterns</param-name>
             <param-value>/resources/*</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/springapp-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <display-name>template</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
            <session-timeout>90000</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
            <error-code>404</error-code>
            <location>/login.jsp</location>
    </error-page>           

</web-app>
```

here is spring xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:security="http//www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

here is spring security xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">
    <beans:bean id="SpringAuthenticationProvider" class="com.spring.SpringAuthenticationProvider"></beans:bean>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="SpringAuthenticationProvider"></authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <!--  ############################################# -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login    login-page="/login"
                       default-target-url="/main"
                       username-parameter="j_username"
                       password-parameter="j_password"
                       authentication-failure-url="/login?auth=fail"/>      
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('admin')"></intercept-url>                                                                                                 
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"></intercept-url> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/main" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login"></logout>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>
    </http>
</beans:beans>
```

here is my authenticator:

```
package com.spring;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

public class SpringAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger( SpringAuthenticationProvider.class );

    @Override
    public boolean supports( Class<? extends Object> authentication )
    {
        return true;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    } 
    */   

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate( Authentication authentication ) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        List<GrantedAuthority> grants = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        grants.add( new SimpleGrantedAuthority( "admin" ) );
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( username , "" , grants );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to change login page to point to /login and previous j_username/j_password to username/password in the jsp